# Merge the [uinavigation] tag into the [uinavigationcontroller] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [uinavigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uinavigation) tag associated with certain iOS questions has no meaning or value (as there's no such class/construct) and should be merged with the [uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uinavigationcontroller) tag.

Sadly, I'm responsible for its creation (I was recently awarded the 'Taxonomist' badge on this basis) but at least I can hopefully ensure that its days are numbered.